# How to connetct (accessing) to IBM cloud object store swift from R?

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, openstack-swift, object-storage

How to connect to IBM cloud object swift  with R?
I've had that informations:

```
auth_url = "https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0",    
username = "my_user_name",    
password = "my_pass",    
container = "my_container",    
filename = "my_filename.csv")
```

I tried Rpackages from git.. but nothing worked.

Comment: There is a code to execute for connecting. I have it on my pc at home. In 5 hours I will be home and update the answer

Comment: Thank you. I'll be waiting.

Comment: @Seymour I'm sorry. but  can you send any code for connecting?

Comment: I cannot find the R script only the python...